# Make Doxygen Document the doxygen.config File

Tags: doxygen

I want to add doxygen tags to the actual doxygen.config file.  Why?  I want to document why we chose certain settings.

I set the following in the doxygen config file:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = *.config=Python
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.h \
                         *.md \
                         *.cpp \
                         path/to/config/file/doxygen.config
```

I added the following to the beginning of the config file:

```
## @file
#

## @page doxygen settings
# hello
```

However, I get nothing but doxygen.config in the file list.

Anyone know how to document the config file?

Comment: You probably will have had the message: Adding custom extension mapping: .*.config will be treated as language python in your output. When looking in the manual we see the example: use: inc=Fortran f=C. So according to this the .* has to be removed (according to my test it works, I see the world hello)

Comment: For those following along, the output for the config file was pretty bad. I had to encapsulate the whole variable section with:

    ## \addtogroup tag title
    #  \{

    ## \brief Exclude system specific path names from the output
    #
    #  \detail NO will prevent user specific path info from showing
    #  up in the documentation (i.e. /home/username/)
    #
    FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO 
    ...
    ## \}

Otherwise only the brief statement will be available.